# Error cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'int' in assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I know it's been asked,

but I still can't find a way out

I have to create data which will be sorted by student ID number

I hope you can help me out

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int NIM[10];
    string nama[10], alamat[10];
    char golongan_darah[10];
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
       cout << "Masukkan data siswa ke-" << i+1 << endl;
       cout << "NIM : "; cin >> NIM[i];
       cout << "Nama : "; cin >> nama[i];
       cout << "Alamat : "; cin >> alamat[i];
       cout << "Golongan Darah ('A'/'B'/'AB'/'O') : "; cin >> golongan_darah[i];
    }

     int pivot;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j=i+1; j<10; j++){
            if (NIM[i] > NIM[j]) {
              pivot= NIM[i];
              NIM[i]=NIM[j];
              NIM[j]=pivot;
              pivot= nama[i];
              nama[i]=nama[j];
              nama[j]=pivot;
              pivot= alamat[i];
              alamat[i]=alamat[j];
              alamat[j]=pivot;
              pivot= golongan_darah[i];
              golongan_darah[i]=golongan_darah[j];
              golongan_darah[j]=pivot;
            }
        }
    }
      cout << "  NIM  |  Nama  |  Alamat  | Golongan Darah" << endl;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << NIM [i] << nama[i] << alamat[i] << golongan_darah[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

it gets error on `pivot= nama[i];` and `pivot= alamat[i];`

thanks in advance

Comment: Please add error to your question.

Comment: You are trying to assign a string to an integer. There is no automatic conversion between the two. Assuming you're doing a bubble sort, you need to use a temporary string variable for the strings, in addition to the one you're using for integers.

Comment: The Error is self-Explanatory. You cannot assign string value to integer. Pivot is being declared as integer here.

Comment: @ChrisMM I'm trying to sort the student ID numbers, other data like Name [nama], Address [alamat], and Blood Type[golongan_darah] just follows it

Comment: @Tushar so what shoul i do? why is the first pivot 'pivot= NIM[i]'  not an error?

Comment: @Ayari In the first line itself you are defining 'NIM' as int. That is the reason you're not getting an error.

Comment: @Tushar then do I have to define 'nama' and 'alamat' as strings too? what about 'golongan_darah'? is it also defined as char?

Comment: nama and alamat are already strings. And golongan_darah is defined as char. I have posted a working solution let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a string value to an integer, you can fix this by using the `stoi()` function. This will take a string and convert it into an integer datatype.

```
pivot= stoi(nama[i]);

pivot= stoi(alamat[i]);
```

Here is some more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

Comment: This probably would not work, and would cause `stoi` to throw. Presumably `nama` is "name" or similar, and does not hold a number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a temporary variable to switch the order in the array. You've already done this with the `pivot` for the integers, however, this does not work with strings.

```
int pivot;
std::string temp;
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<10; j++){
        if (NIM[i] > NIM[j]) {
            pivot= NIM[i]; // NIM stores integers, so this is fine
            NIM[i]=NIM[j];
            NIM[j]=pivot;
            temp= nama[i]; // nama stores strings, so use the new string temp variable
            nama[i]=nama[j];
            nama[j]=temp;
            temp= alamat[i]; // alamat stores strings, so use the new string temp variable
            alamat[i]=alamat[j];
            alamat[j]=temp;
            pivot= golongan_darah[i]; // golongan_darah is stores chars, these can be stored in int
            golongan_darah[i]=golongan_darah[j];
            golongan_darah[j]=pivot;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::swap`

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<10; j++){
        if (NIM[i] > NIM[j]) {
            std::swap( NIM[i], NIM[j] );
            std::swap( nama[i], nama[j] );
            std::swap( alamat[i], alamat[j] );
            std::swap( golongan_darah[i], golongan_darah[j] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int NIM[10];
    string nama[10], alamat[10];
    char golongan_darah[10];
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
       cout << "Masukkan data siswa ke-" << i+1 << endl;
       cout << "NIM : "; cin >> NIM[i];
       cout << "Nama : "; cin >> nama[i];
       cout << "Alamat : "; cin >> alamat[i];
       cout << "Golongan Darah ('A'/'B'/'AB'/'O') : "; cin >> golongan_darah[i];
    }

     int pivot;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j=i+1; j<10; j++){
            if (NIM[i] > NIM[j]) {
              pivot= NIM[i];
              NIM[i]=NIM[j];
              NIM[j]=pivot;
              pivot= stoi(nama[i]); //as pivot is int type nama is changed using stoi() function.
              nama[i]=nama[j];
              nama[j]=pivot;
              pivot= stoi(alamat[i]);  //as pivot is int type nama is changed using stoi() function.
              alamat[i]=alamat[j];
              alamat[j]=pivot;
              pivot= golongan_darah[i];
              golongan_darah[i]=golongan_darah[j];
              golongan_darah[j]=pivot;
            }
        }
    }
      cout << "  NIM  |  Nama  |  Alamat  | Golongan Darah" << endl;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << NIM [i] << nama[i] << alamat[i] << golongan_darah[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: it says [Error] 'stoi' was not declared in this scope

Comment: am i change the compiler or change it to .c ?

Comment: This isn't going to work. It will just give a compiler error when you try to assign `nama[j]=pivot;` and `alamat[j]=pivot;`. Name and address aren't integers. Just use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) to swap values instead of this.

Comment: std::stoi was introduced in C++11. Make sure your compiler settings are correct and your compiler supports C++11.

Comment: @Tushar i see, now i get the problem
thank you for helping, it's for my college task